# How to properly model system requirements in UML (Sparx Enterprise Architect)

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, requirements, requirements-management

I have a list of system requirements that I have imported from IBM Rational DOORS, and I am curious as to what would be a good way to model their relationships with each other in a diagram.
Which Structural diagram should I use, or should it be one of the Behavioral ones?

What I've currently created are links to the requirements in an Object diagram, but I would like to make these Child diagrams that I can link to Class diagrams as well. Does this mean that in order to not create a unique diagram for every class element it's linked to, it should be a composite diagrams the requirements are linked to?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a too broad question. But here are a few pointers:

- Create two folders inside a Requirements folder: functional and non-functional
- Find some prospective order for the functional requirements that target towards the use cases and create sub-folders in the FR folder.
- Create a rather fixed structure for non-functional Rs like Legal, Performance, Security, etc. (Google will give you some nice lists)
- Functional Rs are related to UCs in first place. What I do is to create a UC context diagram inside the UC (which I make composite for the UC) that has the UC in the middle and the Rs traced to it
- Having R-diagrams inside the R-folders can be handy but is not necessary
- NFRs link to implementation details in a later phase. Where appropriate, a trace to the NFR is set in a context diagram of a class.
- Finally all Rs should have at least one trace relation. You could control that by replacing them with a `<<realized>>` relation later.

These are only a few points. There are a lot of books dealing with this topic, so don't expect a complete answer here.

Comment: I believe all these requirements are functional. If I'm reading correctly you would make a composite diagram for them?   
ETA: I've never taken a software course outside of a C programming and Microprocessors class that covered some C, x86, and PIC so I'm not quite sure what the Use Cases are

Comment: Use cases describe the added value of the system under consideration (create a UC diagram in EA and you see the notation). If you have just functional Rs your RM has done something wrongly. There's a high percentage of NFRs (say at least 10% of all Rs). I said UC diagram inside the UC and a Class D inside classes. It does not really matter which you take.